# Referência indefinida compilando com g++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, compilação, visibilidade

Normalmente uso o g++ para compilar meus código, mas agora que comecei a aprender `template` não consigo compilar por nada, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
g++ -c pilha.cpp pilha-infinita.cpp
g++ pilha.o pilha-infinita.o -o pilha.exe

    pilha-infinita.o: na função `main':
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x2c): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::vazio()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x3f): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::topo()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x69): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::~pilha()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x8b): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::~pilha()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Segue os códigos dos arquivos pilha.h, pilha.cpp e pilha-infinita.cpp abaixo:

//pilha.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class elemento
{
    T dado;
    elemento<T> *prox;
};

template <class T>
class pilha
{
private:
    elemento<T> *top;
public:
    pilha() { top = NULL; }
    bool empilha(T);
    T topo();
    T pop();
    bool vazio();
    ~pilha();

};
```

//pilha.cpp

```
#include "pilha.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


template <class T>
pilha<T>::~pilha()
{
    delete [] top;
}

template <class T>
bool pilha<T>::empilha(T x)
{
    if (top==NULL)
    {
        top = new elemento<T>;
        top->dado = x;
        top->prox = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        elemento<T> *aux = new elemento<T>;
        aux->dado = x;
        aux->prox = top;
        top = aux;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <class T>
T pilha<T>::topo()
{
    if (!vazio())
    {
        return top->dado;
    }
    return -1; //RETORNA -1 QUANDO A PILHA ESTA VAZIA
}

template <class T>
T pilha<T>::pop()
{
    if (vazio())
    {
        return -1; //RETORNA -1 QUANDO A PILHA ESTA VAZIA
    }
    else
    {
        T aux = top->dado;
        top = top->prox;
        return aux;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool pilha<T>::vazio()
{
    return (top==NULL);
}
```

//pilha-infinita.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pilha.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pilha<int> p;
    if (!p.vazio())
    {
        cout<<p.topo()<< endl;
    }
    p.empilha(1);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(2);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(3);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(4);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(5);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(6);
    p.empilha(7);
    p.empilha(8);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(9);
    p.empilha(10);
    p.empilha(11);
    p.empilha(12);
    p.empilha(13);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(14);

    cout<<p.topo()<< endl;

    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Depois de inserir o public está dando os seguintes erros:

```
pilha-infinita.o: na função `main':
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x2c): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::vazio()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x3f): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::topo()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x69): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x75): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x9f): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0xab): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0xd5): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0xe1): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x10b): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x117): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x141): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x14d): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x177): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x188): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x199): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x1cf): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x202): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x213): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x21f): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x249): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::empilha(int)'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x255): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::topo()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x27a): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x29f): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x2c4): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x2e9): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x30e): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.o:pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x333): mais referências indefinidas para seguir `pilha<int>::pop()'
pilha-infinita.o: na função `main':
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x3a7): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::~pilha()'
pilha-infinita.cpp:(.text+0x3c9): referência indefinida para `pilha<int>::~pilha()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Acredito que seja por que o "pilha.h" já esta dentro do "pilha.cpp"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema modificando o include no arquivo pilha-infinita.cpp.

No lugar de:

```
#include "pilha.h"
```

Coloquei:

```
#include "pilha.cpp"
```

Não entendi bem o porque disso, mas funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Mude isto:

```
template <class T>
class elemento {
    public:
        T dado;
        elemento<T> *prox;
};
```

Você não pode acessar dados privados da classe. Lembre-se que classes têm seus membros privados por *default*, ao contrário das `structs`.

Acredito que este possa ser o problema ou pelo menos um problema. Não é o mesmo processo mas veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Q40ImQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ijeljwll-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/PrivateMember.cpp). Sem esta alteração não compilava. É provável que a falha na compilação estava falhando a *linkedição*.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class elemento {
    public:
        T dado;
        elemento<T> *prox;
};

template <class T>
class pilha {
private:
    elemento<T> *top;
public:
    pilha() { top = NULL; }
    bool empilha(T);
    T topo();
    T pop();
    bool vazio();
    ~pilha();
};

template <class T>
pilha<T>::~pilha() {
    delete [] top;
}

template <class T>
bool pilha<T>::empilha(T x) {
    if (top == NULL) {
        top = new elemento<T>;
        top->dado = x;
        top->prox = NULL;
        return true;
    } else {
        elemento<T> *aux = new elemento<T>;
        aux->dado = x;
        aux->prox = top;
        top = aux;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <class T>
T pilha<T>::topo() {
    if (!vazio()) return top->dado;
    return -1; //RETORNA -1 QUANDO A PILHA ESTA VAZIA
}

template <class T>
T pilha<T>::pop() {
    if (vazio()) return -1; //RETORNA -1 QUANDO A PILHA ESTA VAZIA
    else {
        T aux = top->dado;
        top = top->prox;
        return aux;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool pilha<T>::vazio() { return (top==NULL); }

using namespace std;

int main() {
    pilha<int> p;
    if (!p.vazio()) {
        cout<<p.topo()<< endl;
    }
    p.empilha(1);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(2);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(3);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(4);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(5);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(6);
    p.empilha(7);
    p.empilha(8);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(9);
    p.empilha(10);
    p.empilha(11);
    p.empilha(12);
    p.empilha(13);
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    p.empilha(14);
    cout<<p.topo()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
    cout<<p.pop()<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Fiz a modificação, mas deu mais erros de referência indefinida. O estranho é que quando coloco o código todo  em um arquivo só funciona normalmente.

Comment: Existe alguma razão para não fazer o processo de compilação por completo sem o `-c`? Não me parece ter nada errado na linha de comando que você colocou e o código com esta alteração compila. Mas se deu outro erros você pode mostrá-los. Embora não sei se vou conseguir ajudar porque não parece ter muito segredo. É uma pena que eu não tenha o compilador para testar. Eu não me lembro se causa problemas mas de qualquer forma o ideal é colocar o `#include "pilha.h"` depois dos `includes` do sistema.

Comment: Inseri os erros no final da pergunta.. Dê uma olhada por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Como se trata de uma class template, tens de colocar a implementação das funções no `pilha.h`, de forma a que sempre que instancies um novo objeto, o compilador saiba como interpretar o template e crie uma nova classe específica. Isto é, `pilha<int>` e `pilha<float>` são interpretadas como classes diferentes e são criadas separadamente pelo compilador -> Conclusão, elimina o `pilha.cpp` e escreve as funções todas no `pilha.h`.

Em alternativa a colocar as implementações no `pilha.h`, podes, no `pilha.cpp`, fazer o que se chama instanciação explícita, e coloar todos os templates que necessitas no fim do ficheiro. Por exemplo, se necessitas de pilhas para `int` e `float` podes escrever no fim do `pilha.cpp`:

```
...
...

template <class T>
bool pilha<T>::vazio()
{
    return (top==NULL);
}

template class pilha<int>;
template class pilha<float>;
etc...
```